# Create smooth animations on video from camera

Tags: html, html5-canvas, augmented-reality

I am working on a project where i need to place a image file on the detected object as here: https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/blob/master/examples/example_sunglasses_jquery.htm .

I can complete my objective with this example.

But how do i make the image file to be stable to stick to the persons head 
.

https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect
If you have a close look of the PICK YOUR GLASS video, it causes a jerk/zoom in-out effect on the glass image file when tracking your head at some cases. How can i prevent this or make this happen in a smooth way.

Comment: First, nice project!  Does your app need real-time display?  If not, I would suggest buffering the video so you can sample a faster frame rate and thereby reduce the "jerk".

Comment: Yeah mark,i need a real time display and works mostly in the same manner as in example.How can i reduce the "jerk" to create a pleasant experience to user.

Comment: OK, expanding my thought: You can get less “jerk” by anticipating where the glasses will need to be next. Here’s how: You can control the fps of animation frame by wrapping it in setInterval [ function draw(){ setTimeout(function(){ requestAnimationFrame(draw); //draw stuff }, 1000 / myDesiredFps); } ].   Then you can buffer the video and “look ahead” to see where the glasses need to be in future frames and nudge the glasses towards that position.  Since requestAnimationFrame tries to present at 60fps and the eye still sees motion at 30fps, you have “extra” frames to look-ahead.

Comment: @ markE can you make it more brief